# remover zeros sql

Tags: sql

Tenho um campo **EUW0**10598260, e precisava que ficasse **EUW**1598260

Preciso de remover um campo especifico

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 'EUW' + substring(campo,patindex('%[^EUW0 ]%',campo + ' ')
       ,len(campo)) AS campo1
       ,campo2
  FROM [tabela]
 WHERE campo3 = 'cp'
   AND campo LIKE '%EUW0%'
```

Comment: se o prefixo EUW0 for sempre no início da string voce pode usar o SUBSTR.

Comment: o que complica é EUW010 tem que ficar EUW1. Se for EUW012 ficaria EUW12, certo? A pergunta não está clara. Precisa explicar qual o padrão dessa string.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso através de REGEX:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(campo,'EUW.1.','EUW1') from tabela
```

Assim o '0' anterior e posterior ao 1 será descartado.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta. Caso seja somente substituir o EUW0 por EUW você pode fazer um replace comum

Comment: quero retirar os 0 EUW010=> euw1

Comment: somente 'select REGEXP_REPLACE(campo,'EUW010','EUW1') from tabela ' será suficiente

Comment: mas se tiver um dois pelo meio ja foste xD

Comment: São sempre a mesma quantidade de dígitos?

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE(campo,'EUW0[1-9]0', 'EUW' || (select substr(campo,5,1) from tabela where REGEXP_LIKE (nome,'EUW0[1-9]0'))) from tabela